# Tomoyo Linux: Have a private folder, that can't be read by default

Tags: linux, arch-linux, security

Is it possible to specify folders, eg:

`/home/$user/private`

that can not be listed, read or written to by any application in the default profile 0, but only with programs where I specify this as rule?

Example:

Store SSH-Keys in such a special folder and run a program that has no policy yet normally as my user. This program should then not be able to do anything with the [files in the] special folder. When I open my ssh client, I want it to be able to read the keys.

I'm using Tomoyo Linux 2.5 on Arch Linux.

Just to avoid confusion: Tomoyo Linux is not a Linux distribution, it is a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control).

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into Tomoyo, the simplest likely solution would be to set permissions 070 on the protected folder and then use the setgid bit to allow access by the appropriate programs.

This would require further thinking / control if you have multiple users on the system and want to limit them separately however.